# Meteor iron router pathFor or equivalent in helper

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm just trying to refer to an iron router route by name in a helper, rather than hard coding the url. So when the user clicks on a button, they are redirected to the item route with the id from the data-id attribute of the button.

**items.html**

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right" data-id={{_id}}>View</button>
```

**items.js**

```
Template.items.events({
  'click button': function(e) {
    // This works but is hard coding the path
    Router.go("/item/" + ($(e.currentTarget).data('id')));
    // This doesn't work but is there an alternative method of doing this
    Router.go(pathFor('item' id=_id))
  }
});
```

**router.js**

```
Router.route('/item/:_id', {
  name: 'item'
});
```

I can of course use pathFor in a template like so:

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'item' id=_id}}">View</a>
```

Or specify a data attribute:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right" data-path={{pathFor 'item' id=_id}}>View</button>
```

But wondered if there is an alternative / neater way to do it? If not I might revert back to using  tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in luck, this is actually quite simple (though not yet made explicit in the docs).

Given the route `item` that takes an `_id`:

```
Router.route('/item/:_id', {
  name: 'item'
});
```

There are actually two options.  Option 1:

```
Router.go('item', variableWithIdValue)
```

Or, if you have an object with a member variable/function that matches the route's parameter (in this case, `_id`):

```
Router.go('item', itemInstance)
```

In the second case, Iron:Router notices that the passed parameter has a member variable/function that matches the parameter defined in the route's path, so it calls it instead of using the passed parameter itself.

EDIT: I should mention that you may also pass a hash, such as:

```
Router.go('item', {_id: variableWithIdValue})
```

This actually *is* described in the docs here:

https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#named-routes

Comment: Wow, I even looked over the docs earlier and missed that last one.. Thanks!

Comment: What if you don't want the browser to navigate to the URL and instead just want to use a string of the URL inside a helper? Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5):

```
UI._globalHelpers.pathFor(nameofRoute, param1, parmas2....)
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I ended up having to use `Router.path(routeName)`.

Answer (score 2):

First thing,
You don't need to use `data-id` attrib in html, this._id will be available in click event

Second,for the `Router.go` you can use `Router.go("item",{_id:this._id});`
**Code**

```
Template.items.events({
  'click button': function(e) {
     Router.go("item",{_id:this._id});
  }
});
```

Refer to the docs here: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#named-routes